# Case when then result field shows blank value

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a portion of my query. I fail to understand where is the problem in my query. The query is not working. It shows blank field.

If I add `else 'abc'` then 'abc' shows in the field.

```
case cc.min_col
         when 'sm1' 
         then  (select CASE least(SUM(`j100`), SUM(`j119`), SUM(`j128`))
                                WHEN `j100` THEN '100'
                                WHEN `j119` THEN '119'
                                WHEN `j128` THEN '128'
                                ELSE 'abc'
                                END from `smc1a`)
end) as min_no
```

Comment: The `least` part returns a value, not a column name.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is non-standard SQL)

Comment: I am using MYSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
case cc.min_col
         when 'sm1' 
         then  (select CASE least(SUM(`j100`), SUM(`j119`), SUM(`j128`))
                                WHEN SUM(`j100`) THEN '100'
                                WHEN SUM(`j119`) THEN '119'
                                WHEN SUM(`j128`) THEN '128'
                        END from `smc1a`)
end) as min_no
```